# How can I do to extract a pattern in RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework

I have that kind of string :

```
"car model-8789 blue green"
"car model-879 blue green"
"car model-87897189 blue green"
```

And what I want is to extract `model-xxxx` where x are the numbers. I thought to split every string and to do a if and then using a regex but I wonder if there is a better solution to do that directly using RobotFramework ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do string manipulation there usually are no easy ways around it. In this case, if the formatting is reliable, you can get by relatively easily. But if its not, then you'll either need some regexp or for-loops to find that data reliably.

You should only need to split the string once, no regexp needed. You'll need to use [String Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#library-documentation-top) and [Collections Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#library-documentation-top).

```py
*** Settings ***
Library    BuiltIn
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Get Model From Line
    ${STRING}=    Set Variable    car model-8789 blue green
    @{LINE}=    Split String    ${STRING}    ${SPACE}    # = ['car', 'model-8789', 'blue', 'green']
    FOR    ${WORD}    IN    @{LINE}
        IF    'model' in ${WORD}
            ${MODEL}=    Set Variable    ${WORD}
            Exit For Loop
        END
    END
    Log    ${MODEL}
```

If possible you might want to look for a way to make the input in some structured format, like csv, to make this more robust.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that sometimes I can have also that `model-8789 car blue green` :/

Comment: Added an example of a for loop to the answer - Since your structure is not reliable, it is more up to your preference whether this or regexp is more natural to you. I don't think that the performance either way will be a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regex.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     String
Library     Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    ${String}       Set Variable        car model-8789 blue green
    ${Match}       Get Regexp Matches     ${String}       model-[0-9]*
    Log     ${Match}
```